# Issue decoding Async/Await response in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await, codable

I am trying to submit an order to production but keep getting a decoding error and I have no idea where it's going wrong.

This is the full error:

> ERROR DECODING keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil) ("id").", underlyingError: nil))

My Model:

```
struct PrintifyOrderResponse: Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

My function/call:

```
func fetch<T: Codable>(type: PrintifyRequestType) async throws -> T? {
    let req = type.getRequest()
    
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: req)
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let decoded = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        return decoded
    } catch {
        print("ERROR DECODING")
        print(error)
        print()
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

in async func:

```
do {
        var res: PrintifyOrderResponse?
        res = try await service.fetch(type: .sendToProduction(id))
        guard let res = res else {
            statusError(message: "Error sending to production")
            return
        }
        
        orderSuccess(id: res.id)
        
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
        statusError()
    }
}
```

The response is quite simple as seen from postman below. I'm not sure why/how this decoding error is happening

[image]

Comment: Print the `data` object to verify you get the expected result back, convert it to string first using `String(data:encoding:)`

Comment: I'd recommend adding a breakpoint or a print statement to see what the content of `data` is. You can convert it to a string to by doing `String(data.utf8)` which will be more readable than raw data. It's possible the app is getting a different response than the screenshot, maybe there's a missing header the server expects.

Comment: are you printing out the same response? For example if server returns error, it may still be JSON of some kind (e.g. `{ "error": "..." }`, so

Comment: You share the POSTMAN response, but not the one you are getting. Add `print("Response str: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of what you shared with us, the response is not what you said you expected. To determine what went wrong, we should add some diagnostics.

So, to diagnose this, you should print the contents of the `data`. You should also capture and print the `response`.

```swift
func fetch<T: Decodable>(type: PrintifyRequestType) async throws -> T {
    let request = type.getRequest()
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    
    do {
        guard
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200...299 ~= response.statusCode
        else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
            
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "cannot represent as string")")
        print("response: \(String(describing: response))")
        print(error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

While we‘re here, we should probably re-`throw` the error and change the return type to not be optional.